# Uninstall-Package xxx –RemoveDependencies doesn't uninstall the dependencies

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I am trying to uninstall jQuery package using the –RemoveDependencies flag however it's complaining that other jQuery packages depend on it.

Shouldn't this flag make NuGet uninstall all the dependencies?
Using Nuget Manager 3.4.4 in VS 2015.

Comment: Can you share the detailed message you get?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not how the RemoveDependencies flag works. It is used to remove the packages that the package being removed depends on, not the other way around.

If you have jQuery and jQuery.Validation installed you can remove both of these with the RemoveDependencies option by uninstalling jQuery.Validation.

```
uninstall-package jquery.validation -RemoveDependencies
```

However if you try to directly uninstall jquery even with the RemoveDependencies option it will fail with an error since jQuery.Validation depends on it.

Comment: First.. I don't know how your answer is different then what I am asking. I was asking why it doesn't remove the dependencies then the package. Then your answer doesn't seem to be correct. See other answe

Comment: If you have jQuery.Validation which depends on jQuery then you can run `uninstall-package jquery.validation -RemoveDependencies` which will remove both jQuery.Validation and jQuery. You cannot use RemoveDependencies with a command line `uninstall-package jquery` if jQuery.Validation is installed since the command does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the description for –RemoveDependencies from [this link](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/Package-Manager-Console-PowerShell-Reference), it mentioned that "Uninstalls the package and its unused dependencies.". It means you need to uninstall the package that dependent on the dependencies package at the same time.

If you want to remove the dependencies, I suggest you uninstall all packages that contains the packages dependent on it. And then reinstall the package with following command, which will install the package only without dependencies.

> install-package PackageName **-IgnoreDependencies**

Comment: The package that I want to uninstall installed those dependencies, not me.   Whether they are used or not, I don't know and it should be the package's problem. I know I have to remove the dependencies first but why do I have to go through these manual steps when I didn't install them. The parent package should go through its dependencies and figure if they are used or not and then uninstall them. This flag's functionality seems to be deficient.

Comment: The dependencies are installed because the parent package need them. If you remove the dependencies first, which will lead to the parent package could not work as expected. This is why if the dependencies are relied by other parent, it will not be removed. The function of -RemoveDependencies flag is correct because it let us know which denpendencies are not removed with the reasons. If you get error message about other packages rely on the dependencies, it means you just need to uninstall the parent package.